# How to provide an array of positions to Create Points Node via Blueprint variables?

Tags: procedural-generation, blueprints, unreal-5

I wanted to use the **Create Points** node from PCG to align objects in a certain way. For this I've created a variable in my Blueprint `ArrayOfPosition` with type Array of Vectors. Now when I try to get this variable in my PCG using **Get Actor Property** it throws this error:

> Error while creating an attribute for property 'ArrayOfPositions'. Either the property type is not supported or by PCG or attribute creation failed.

I think arrays of vectors are not supported... Is there a workaround available to assign an Array of Positions to Create Points using Blueprint Variables?